# Moments of matrix multiplied with diagonal matrix with Gaussians

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a circulant Toeplitz matrix $T$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with IID zero mean complex Gaussians with circular symmetry along its main diagonal.

How do I compute the moments $E[(D^HTD)^n]$?
The Wick formula seems to come in handy, but quickly gets complicated for large $n$ and I would really like to have (if possible) a neat formula in the spectrum of $T$.

Thanks